# Loopback-4 Add timestamp createdAt & updatedAt through model

Tags: loopback4

I had taken look hooks provided for lower version but I want to know how can I add timestamp `createdAt` & `updatedAt` through models without interacting same for timestamps in controller.

I had worked on `Rails` but `Loopback-4` is something new to me and not as flexible as `Rails`.
I require this timestamps only for few specific models

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in following way:-

**In Model File:**

```
@property({
  type: 'date',
  default: () => new Date()
})
created ? : string;

@property({
  type: 'date',
  default: () => new Date()
})
modified ? : string;
```

**In Repository File:**

```
constructor(
  @inject('datasources.db') dataSource: DbDataSource,  
) {
  super(User, dataSource);

  (this.modelClass as any).observe('persist', async (ctx: any) => {
    ctx.data.modified = new Date();
  });
}
```

Comment: will give a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm bumping into this in 2022 and the suggested answer is now relying on *legacy* code.

The `modelClass` field is of type `PersistedModelClass` coming from `import legacy from 'loopback-datasource-juggler';` which is backward-compatibility for operation hooks in Loopback v4.

See [packages/repository/src/repositories/legacy-juggler-bridge.ts in Github](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/blob/c1ae1bcc13fdba33b5d0c48cdeb0858176ff1208/packages/repository/src/repositories/legacy-juggler-bridge.ts)

The current solution is to use mixins as per the following issue/comment on Github: https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/issues/1857#issuecomment-618207056